# Service activator method mapping using @Header annotation in Spring Integration

Tags: spring, annotations, messaging, spring-integration

I'm developing web app using Spring Integration to route my messages, but I have some problems with passing my header value. My message goes through router and service activator.

The header value is available in a routing method of my router so it seems to be ok. Let's assume that it is not a problem (I checked this by disabling my service activator).

When it comes to my service activator method the following error is thrown: 
"Failed to find any valid Message-handling methods named ***process*** on target class MyService."

**my-spring-integration.xml**

```
<channel id="route" />
<service-activator method="process" input-channel="route" ref="myService" output-channel="myOutputChannel" />
```

**MyRouter.java**

```
@Component
public class MyRouter {

   public String router(String message, @Header("isValid") boolean isValid) {
      // isValid is "true"
      return "route";
   } 

}
```

**MyService.java**

```
@MessageEndpoint
@Transactional
public class MyService {

   public void process(String message, @Header("isValid") boolean isValid) {
      ...
   }

}
```

Why is that? Are headers values erased after routing? Or my configuration is wrong? I tried to add @ServiceActivator annotation to my process method, but it didn't help.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I tried with a configuration along the lines of what you have and it worked cleanly for me. Can you please provide your version of Spring Integration

Comment: Any way for you to upgrade to 2.0+ version, 1.0.4 is a fairly old version?

Comment: Not really, but as far as know 1.04 version should not be the problem in this case.

Comment: I guess you were right. My application support 'Headers', but it doesn't support 'Header' annotation. Don't know the exact reason of that, but supposedly it's spring integration version issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm working with legacy code and it was probably caused by old spring integration version. My application support '@Headers', but it doesn't support '@Header' annotation. @Header annotation was accepted in my router which is interface and not in my service activator which does not implement any interface. I suspect it was caused by old version of spring integration or cglib.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that this is caused by having an `@Transactional` annotation on a Service which doesn't implement any interfaces.

Spring will implement the transactional logic using JDK dynamic proxies, these rely on proxied classes implementing suitable interfaces. There is a Spring blog about this [here](http://blog.springsource.org/2012/05/23/understanding-proxy-usage-in-spring/).

To fix this I would suggest that you create an interface called MyService with a single method called process. Then have you service implement this interface.

Comment: Thx for link to the article, but I use CGLib proxies which doesn't require interfaces. I provided default constructor (required) and still no improvement.

Comment: Interesting. In that case I doubt this is the problem!

Comment: I'm working with legacy code and it was probably caused by old spring integration version. Using 'Headers' annotation instead of 'Header' solved the problem. Thx for useful lesson about proxies.